# I want to find video effect

Tags: after-effects, effects

I need a video effect to show a big count of video on my youtube channel.

I want to show a grid of small 64 videos (or more). The camera will start with one video in the center and will be moving away, increase the scale, more and more videos will fall to the scope of the camera.

How can I find such a video effect and buy it?
I tried on https://videohive.net but do not have success with it.
In what film or video I can find such an effect? I saw it in some films, but do not remember where.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to look for "Multi Video" on VideoHive. It gives me some results similar to what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

My first port of call was to look on videohive too. But in the end i ended up creating the grid of videos then using the parent tool to assign all videos to the central video as the parent and just apply a scale to that video which controls the scale of the rest.

Comment: An alternative method would be to use a 3D scene, with the videos in a grid and moving the camera away.